# Laravel form validation doesn't work when in my controller declaring more databases

Tags: php, laravel

I declare a variable containing the database so that the blade can select, but when doing so, the validation does not work. Please help me. Thank you very much.

`this is the variable I call in the database to use select in the blade`.

```
public function new_department(){
    //return view('admin.new-department');

    $manage_faculties=DB::table('faculties')->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

    $all_manage_faculties=view('admin.new-department')->with('manage_faculties', $manage_faculties);

    return view('layouts.master')->with('admin.new-department', $all_manage_faculties);
}
```

`Here is the validation I use in the insert information and database`.

```
 public function save_new_department(Request $request){
    $data = [];
    $data['department_name'] = $request->input('department_name');
    $data['description'] = $request->input('description');
    $data['faculty_id'] = $request->input('faculty_name');


    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'department_name' => 'required|min:3|max:100|unique:departments',
            'description' => 'required|max:500',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->with('toast_error', $validator->messages()->all()[0])->withInput();
        }

        DB::table('departments')->insert($data);
        return redirect('/admin/departments/new')->withSuccess('Post Created Successfully!');
    }

}
```

`display it in the blade`

After entering data whether it is true or false, it is not possible to report an error on the screen.After entering data whether it is true or false, it is not possible to report an error on the screen.

```
        <form class="mt-3"method="post" action="{{ url('admin/department/new-department') }}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Create a Department</h5>
                    </div>
                    <!--end of modal head-->
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group row align-items-center" {{ $errors->get('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}>
                            <label class="col-2">Department</label>
                            <input class="form-control col" type="text" placeholder="Department name" name="department_name" required/>
                            @foreach($errors->get('name') as $error)
                                <span class="help-block">{{ $error }}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                            <label class="col-2">Faculty</label>
                            <select  name="faculty_name" class="form-control col" required>
                                <option value="" selected>Select a Faculty</option>

                                @foreach($manage_faculties as $key => $cate_pro)
                                    <option value="{{$cate_pro->id}}">{{$cate_pro->faculty_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-2">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control col" rows="10" placeholder="Write something here..." name="description" required  ></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--end of modal body-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button role="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Post
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I'm seeing a whole lot of `DB::table()` in here. Do you not have Eloquent models set up for these? What isn't working here? Are you getting redirected as expected? Does `dd($errors)` show any errors after a failed validation?

Comment: All works normally except that the message of new addition and failure is not displayed on the web page.

Comment: "Normally" doesn't mean much. Does `dd($errors)` show any errors after a failed validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) for displaying errors in Laravel.

Why did you put :

```
{{ $errors->get('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}
```

inside a "div" like a attribute ?